# How to fetch email addresses of Google plus circles (Friends added in Google plus circles)

Tags: android, google-plus

I am able to login with google plus and have fetch the list of all the people who are in my google plus circle but now i also want to get the email addresses of all people in my circle is there are way to do it? I have tried this code but it does not work.

```
public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, final PersonBuffer personBuffer,
            String nextPageToken) 
    {
        if (status.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
        {           
            try
            {
                //Add all friends ids in an arraylist
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                //Loop through all the ids of google plus friends
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                {
                    //mListItems.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                    //mListIds.add(personBuffer.get(i).getId());  

                    friends_gplus_Ids += personBuffer.get(i).getId() + ",";
                    //Log.d("Emails", personBuffer.get(i).getOrganizations().toString());
                    //personBuffer.get(i).getEmails().size();

                    if((personBuffer.get(i).getEmails().size() > 0)) 
                    {
                        Log.d("Emails", personBuffer.get(i).getEmails().get(0).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("Emails", "Null");
                    }                                   
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                personBuffer.close(); 
            }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15385160/1292203 have a look at it

Comment: i am already getting the email address of the person who is logged in, i want to fetch the email addresses of his (logged in person) friends. So that i can send email/Invitation to use my app

Comment: No Have not got the solution

Comment: any solution for this issue guys.. i also have.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: was not able to find any solution. It was 3 years ago so not sure if it is possible now

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to request both the Google+ scopes and the [Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) scope (`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds`). You would then need to request the user's contacts and find those with [Google+ profile URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802267/get-google-id-from-google-contacts), which will look something like:

```
<gContact:website href='http://www.google.com/profiles/1234567890' rel='profile'/>
```

Then you'd look to see if an email address also existed for that contact as a sibling element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i did not understand. Could you elaborate your answer little more?