# How to get circles or contacts emails of user from g+ APIs?

Tags: android, google-plus, social-networking

I am able to get user email through Google plus login in my app , but i am not getting user circles emails. Is it Possible or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch email addresses of Google plus circles (Friends added in Google plus circles)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114453/how-to-fetch-email-addresses-of-google-plus-circles-friends-added-in-google-plu)